# sending file name on a blank page ajax call to node

Tags: node.js

it is working fine. the only problem is after execution it keeps waiting for response after setting header.. but after a while it shows no response on page it was set also it keeps waiting.. i have tried using "res.end()" it stops the response but shows only blank page here is the code..

here is the ajax code for it

```
var formData = new FormData($('#cover_file_form')[0]);

$.ajax({
    url: '/cropImg',
    data: formData,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data){
        setTimeout(
    function() {
           $('.container-coverscreen img').attr('src','images-esct/cropped/'+data.file_name);
        },
        250);
    }
});
```

and on server side

```
app.post('/cropImg',function(req,res){

    // get the temporary location of the file
    var tmp_path = req.files.file_browse_cover.path;

        gm(tmp_path)
            .resize(parseInt(req.body.InputWidth), parseInt(req.body.InputHeight), "!")
            .crop(255, 292, parseInt(req.body.InputLeft), parseInt(req.body.InputTop))
            .write(__dirname + "/public/images-esct/cropped/"+req.files.file_browse_cover.name  , function (err) {

            if(err) throw err;
                console.log(err);
            });

        res.setHeader({file_name: req.files.file_browse_cover.name});
        //res.end('please stop');
})
```

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the status code as well:

```
res.setHeader("Location", "/eventapp");
res.sendStatus(302);
res.end();
```

But it would be easier to just use the `redirect`-method:

`res.redirect('/eventapp');`

Comment: res.redirect('/eventapp')
its working but it refreshes the whole page .. on eventapp page ihave some other values which it sets to default.. isnt there any way to stop refresh? @PatrickD

Comment: thanks.. i was using form submition.. i disabled it and its working now .. thanks again

Comment: Then you need to explain in more detail what do you want. What was your intention when you set the Location-Header?

Comment: sorry for late reply.. i have changed res.redirect to res. send().. i am upload loading image on server and croping it and saving it.. also want to return the file name.. in res.send().. it sends the file on blank page .. i have update some code too .. please help me thanks @PatrickD